# How to scan for ble peripherals without uuid filter in android with the screen off?

Tags: android, service, bluetooth, react-native

I managed to make an android app with react native scan for ble peripherals. I can even scan in the background thru establishing a foreground service. However, its another story with the screen off. Apparently, bluetooth stops scanning without filters. Is there any workaround for this? Thank you!

Comment: I think this is the intended behaviour. What is your use case to scan in the background without filters?

Comment: I need to scan for iOS device that can't broadcast their UUIDs when in background mode when my android screen is off.